# Ubuntu correcting 'za' to 'zæ' while typing

Tags: keyboard, language-support, input-language, input-method

For some reason, after the latest update, whenever I type the <kbd>z</kbd> & <kbd>a</kbd> keys one after the other fast enough, that keystroke is converted to 'zæ'. The a gets changed to 'æ' which isn't even a character in any language I've got installed, which is extremely annoying. ZÆ even in caps...
Using Ubuntu 18.04. The language it's set to is English (US), and this happens both with an English (any) or Spanish (Spain/America) layout.
Dvorak doesn't have that problem though. Weird... I'm using a Razer Blackwidow Chroma with the OpenRazer drivers.

Comment: I've found it also corrects `zo` to `zø`. It appears that the `z` key (`z+a` & `z+o`) is a modifier which produces the weird characters (`æøµ“n`). But there appears to be some hysteresis set up, so it also happens when the sequence is typed fast. Still haven't figured out why it has activated or how to deactivate it.

Comment: The<kbd>z</kbd> key seems to activate those functions that belong to <kbd>AltGr</kbd>. However, when I open the 'Show Keyboard Layout' program, the <kbd>z</kbd> key only triggers the proper key. Weird...